# How to improve my if else logic while appending from list of dicts?

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement

I have a list of dicts `x` with some metadata and I may/may not have another list of just strings `y` without metadata which is a subset of the previous list.

I want to iterate over `x` and append the string with some of the metadata to another list `z`. If I have `y`, I want to just add metadata of the strings in `y` from `x` to `z`.

I have this solution so far and I think this can be improved, if not I will remove the question.

```py
x = [
    {"a": "valuea0", "b": "valueb0"},
    {"a": "valuea1", "b": "valueb1"},
    {"a": "valuea2", "b": "valueb2"},
]
y = ["valueb0", "valueb1"]
z = []

def so_question(x, **kwargs):
    test_kwarg = kwargs.get("test_kwarg", None)

    for item in x:
        test_string = item["b"]
        if test_kwarg:
            if test_string in test_kwarg:
                z.append(
                    {
                        "p": item["a"],
                        "q": item["b"],
                    }
                )
        else:
            z.append(
                {
                    "p": item["a"],
                    "q": item["b"],
                }
            )
    return z

print(so_question(x, test_kwarg=y))
```

Expected output:

```
z = [
    {"a": "valuea0", "b": "valueb0"},
    {"a": "valuea1", "b": "valueb1"},
]
```

How can I improve this if/else logic since I am doing the same thing in both if and else?

Comment: provide expected output

Comment: I have added the output. Just to be clear `y` may/may not be there as kwarg. thanks

Comment: `if not test_kwarg or test_string in test_kwarg: z.append(..)` should be equivalent to what you have

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can combine both the conditions where you append as follows

```
x = [
    {"a": "valuea0", "b": "valueb0"},
    {"a": "valuea1", "b": "valueb1"},
    {"a": "valuea2", "b": "valueb2"},
]
y = ["valueb0", "valueb1"]
z = []

def so_question(x, **kwargs):
    test_kwarg = kwargs.get("test_kwarg", None)

    for item in x:
        test_string = item["b"]
        if not test_kwarg or test_string in test_kwarg:
              z.append(
                  {
                      "p": item["a"],
                      "q": item["b"],
                  }
              )
    return z
print(so_question(x, test_kwarg=y))
```

You else condition is captured in not test_kwarg. In case of if condition, it goes to the or part and, there you can give your nested if condition. Using "or" as either case, you are going to append.